# how to return the minimum value on every nth cell

Tags: excel, formula, modulo

I'm looking for a simple formula to compare and return with the minimum value of every nth cell.

My first value is in cell C26 and there are expected to be an undefined amount of values on the every 47th cell of that column after that.

I've been searching around and generalized a formula as follows:

```
=min(mod(row(C26),47)=0)
```

or

```
=min(offset($C$26,(row()-1)*47,0))
```

But obviously, one of them are giving me the result i wanted (the value in the cells are dates)

I'm hoping that someone would be able to assist?

Thank you!

Comment: it's meant to say:

Comment: it's meant to say "but obviously, NONE of them are giving me the result i wanted (the value in the cells are dates)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, when returning an array of numeric values from the `OFFSET` function, the `N` function makes it work.

If there are no blanks in the range to be tested, you can use something like:

```
=MIN(N(OFFSET($C$26,(ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))-1)*47,0)))
```

entered as an array formula by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`

If there might be blanks in the range, then you can try something like the following, also entered as an array formula:

```
=SMALL(N(OFFSET($C$26,(ROW(INDIRECT("1:100"))-1)*47,0)),1+SUMPRODUCT(N(N(OFFSET($C$26,(ROW(INDIRECT("1:100"))-1)*47,0))=0)))
```

In this case, the first `N` immediately after the `SUMPRODUCT` coerces the Boolean result to `1` or `0`.

Comment: hi Ron, thank you so much for assisting with this question. i'm very bad with this stuff.. my values are expected to have blanks in them, so the second formula worked for me. but now i have value starting C27 and the every 47th value after that to compare for maximum value... initially i was hoping i could just substitute the cell numbers and change "min" to "max" but i didn't work with your second formula... what would i be looking at working with here?

Comment: @kitarika That should work.  `=Max(N(OFFSET($C$27,(ROW(INDIRECT("1:100"))-1)*47,0)))`  The blanks would irrelevant in computing MAX.

Comment: just wanted to thank you for your help! that really helped me out! :)